# charAt gives a non existing value

Tags: java

Hi folks I have a weird problem, as the title says the function charAt is giving me a non existing value.
This is my code

```
String numeroDoc = "20298729700"

int lastNumber = numeroDoc.charAt(numeroDoc.length() - 1) // returns 48
```

But it should be 0, when I make a for loop it returns the rigth value. What am I missing?

Comment: 48 is the numeric value of the character '0'

Comment: `char lastNumber = ..`

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-), which says: *"Returns the **`char`** value at the specified index."* --- It doesn't return an `int`, but a `char`. Then read the Java manual on how a `char` is also a number, to learn why char `'0'` is number `48`, i.e. learn about Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting ASCII value of '0' i.e 48. As you have declared lastNumber as int.

Modify your code as

```
 char lastNumber = numeroDoc.charAt(numeroDoc.length() - 1);
```

Instead of declaring lastNumber as int, declare it as a char.